# Change in measure of Feynman path integral relevant for CFT

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, string-theory, path-integral, noethers-theorem

In Polchinski book while deriving Noether’s theorem when we do variation of some parameter: It is stated (below $2.3.4$) that in addition to some variation of action we also have variation in measure $\int \mathcal{D \phi’}e^{-S[\phi’]} $ as well.

Despite this claim when we calculate the conserved current (ex. $2.3.13$, $2.3.15$) the result is obtained with the measure term held constant. Though we get a change in measure in following fashion
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D\phi’}&=\prod_i d\phi’_i=\prod_id(\phi_i+\delta\phi_i) \\
&=\prod_id\phi_i+\sum_j\left(d(\delta\phi_j)\left(\prod_i^{n-1}d\phi_i\right)\right)
\end{align}

The second term in above expression is order $-1$ in variation parameter therefore it should change the conserved current.

In yellow book of CFT the author claims from the start (ch-$4,5$) that the measure will remain constant. Since I don’t know about measure theory so in case this result borrows some theorem from there I might be negligent about it.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, Polchinski and the yellow book, the authors explicitly state that they will generally assume that the measure remains invariant. When the measure changes non-trivially, this often leads to anomalies. So unless the source you're looking at is thinking about anomalies, they will usually assume the measure does not change.

I should point out though that you can always just calculate the determinant factor for whatever transformation you're doing. This may be a non-trivial calculation (particularly if fermions are involved), but in principle it can always be done. Most transformations we work with are linear in the fields they are transforming, so the determinant ends up just being some overall constant we can discard anyway.